# Is there a way to speed up the library loading in R?

Tags: performance, r, statistics

I have a Rscript that will load `ggplot2` in its first line.

Though loading a library doesn't take much time, as this script may be executed in command line for millions of times so the speed is really important for me.

Is there a way to speed up this loading process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an addition to [@MikeDunlavey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10824958/755257):

Actually, both `library` and `require` check whether the package is already loaded.
Here are some timings with `microbenchmark` I get:

```
> microbenchmark (`!` (exists ("qplot")), 
                  `!` (existsFunction ('qplot')),  
                  require ('ggplot2'),  
                  library ('ggplot2'),   
                  "package:ggplot2" %in% search ())

## results reordered with descending median:
Unit: microseconds
                             expr     min       lq   median       uq     max
3              library("ggplot2") 259.720 262.8700 266.3405 271.7285 448.749
1        !existsFunction("qplot")  79.501  81.8770  83.7870  89.2965 114.182
5              require("ggplot2")  12.556  14.3755  15.5125  16.1325  33.526
4 "package:ggplot2" %in% search()   4.315   5.3225   6.0010   6.5475   9.201
2                !exists("qplot")   3.370   4.4250   5.0300   6.2375  12.165
```

For comparison, loading for the first time:

```
> system.time (library (ggplot2))
   User      System verstrichen 
  0.284       0.016       0.300
```

(these are seconds!)

In the end, as long as the factor 3 = 10 μs between `require` and `"package:ggplot2" %in% search()` isn't needed, I'd go with `require`, otherwise witht the `%in% search ()`.

Comment: Nice work -- I had the same thought about "this ought to get benchmarked". Thanks for doing that, and I will also continue to go with `require()` for clarity without any meaningful performance loss.

Answer (score 9):

Don't restart -- keep a persistent R session and just issue requests to it.  Something like [Rserve](http://rforge.net/Rserve) can provide this, and for example [FastRWeb](http://www.rforge.net/FastRWeb/) uses it very well -- with millsecond round-trips for chart generation.

Comment: This was my thought, too. I'd also add thinking about controlling what loads when R is started. If you want to be efficient, control the profile so that only the required libraries are loaded at start up, including, in this case, ggplot2.

Answer (score 2):

What Dirk said, plus you can use the `exists` function to conditionally load a library, as in

```
if ( ! exists( "some.function.defined.in.the.library" )){
    library( the.library )
}
```

So if you put that in the script you can run the script more than once in the same R session.